# Vocabularies about the speed of walking

Tags: vocabulary, lists

As I'm learning vocabulary, I've learned new words such as stroll, canter, gait, gallop, trot, walk, run, sprint,  etc.. could anyone make a list of words that talks about such things in an ascending order of speed? (Sorry for my incorrect grammar... )

p.s. I've learned that the world 'gallop' can only be used to a horse. So when making the list, please add information as to what animal (or human) the word can be used to.

p.s. Also, if there are other words that describe walking or running that I didn't mention, feel free to add more as I want to learn more words!

Comment: "Gallop" does not always refer to a horse. I found the following sentences at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gallop

"I grabbed my books and galloped out the door."

"The program gallops through early American history."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List questions are [usually off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic) on SE, fyi. That said, I've always found [google results](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=synonym%20stroll) great for finding synonyms (e.g. searching "synonym stroll"), better at times than thesaurus.com IMO. Here are a few great words that might help you, listed roughly in order of ascending speed. Please be aware that the difference in speed between a *saunter* and a *mosey* is generally undefined and highly subjective:

- saunter
- mosey
- amble
- stroll
- scoot
- bound (usually describes an animal, esp. one that leaps as it runs like a mule deer)
- scamper (usually, but not always, used to describe an animal's movement)
- skitter
- hurtle
- charge
- dash
- bolt

**Note:** A lot of these words don't necessarily denote a specific speed relative to others, so it can be hard (or impossible) to say whether dashing or bolting is *faster*. That said, "dashing" is definitely synonymous with "moving fast" and "strolling" is synonymous with "walking slowly", so this list roughly reflects a slow to fast order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a particular order as to which vocabulary is faster than another?

Comment: Updated. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add this one:

[**perambulate**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/perambulate)

> *formal, humorous*
>
> 1) **Walk or travel through or round a place.**
>
> ‘the locals perambulate up and down the thoroughfare’
>
> **with object**
>
> ‘she perambulated the square’